# microsoft navision 2009, checkbox checked

Tags: dynamics-nav-2009

I try to check a checkbox in navision 2009 with the tool box.

I try it like this:

```
  IF CurrForm."Bestaand afleveradres" = TRUE THEN
    MESSAGE('hallo');
```

Bestaand afleveradres is the name of the checkbox

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every control on form in Nav must have SourceExpr property filled with variable name. In your case it must be Boolean variable. Let's say it's called `BoolVar`. This variable is what you must check.

```
IF BoolVar = TRUE THEN
  MESSAGE('hallo');
```

You should really read [some guide](https://www.olofsimren.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/NAV-CAL-Programming-Guide-for-Microsoft-Dynamics-NAV.pdf) first.